# How to search multiple fields and aggregate scores?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out a solution to how I should structure my queries for finding answers to people's questions. For example, based off the dataset I will paste at the end of this post, I would like to query **"Shows about romance"**, and maybe get results like so:

```json
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_score": "31",
      "_source": {
        "anime": "Grisaia no Kajitsu"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": "12",
      "_source": {
        "anime": "Mirai Nikki"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": "7",
      "_source": {
        "anime": "Bakemonogatari"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Grisaia no Kajitsu** shows up as the first result because it's shown in multiple relevant questions, and **Mirai Nikki** is second because it had a higher score than **Bakemonogatari**.

Basically I would like answers that are relevant based off the `question`, `score`, and `tags` field.  Questions that have repeated answers should have a higher score. Any suggestions?

My dataset:

```json
[
  {
    "question": "Looking for romance anime",
    "score": 4,
    "answers": [
      {
        "anime": "Mirai Nikki",
        "score": 8,
        "tags": ["action", "adventure", "death game", "romance"]
      },
      {
        "anime": "Bakemonogatari",
        "score": 3,
        "tags": ["action", "comedy", "romance", "seinen"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Survival Anime",
    "score": 10,
    "answers": [
      {
        "anime": "Grisaia no Kajitsu",
        "score": 4,
        "tags": ["school", "drama", "survival", "romance"]
      },
      {
        "anime": "Kanata no Astra",
        "score": 7,
        "tags": ["action", "comedy", "drama", "space"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Horror and romance anime?",
    "score": 12,
    "answers": [
      {
        "anime": "Grisaia no Kajitsu",
        "score": 15,
        "tags": ["school", "drama", "survival", "romance"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, you can tune various boost params around here and see how it affects your results

```
{
 "_source": ["answers.anime"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "answers.tags": {
                            "value": "Shows about romance",
                            "boost": 2 //weight of tags field
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "question": {
                            "query": "Shows about romance",
                            "boost": 2 //weight of question field
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "function_score": {
                        "min_score": 0.9,
                        "functions": [
                            {
                                "field_value_factor": {
                                    "factor": 1, //weight of score field
                                    "field": "answers.score",
                                    "modifier": "log2p"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Should the term query be `answers.tags`? Also is it possible to just got the `answer.anime` instead of the whole source?

Comment: Also, in my experience its a better idea to have the field u are searching(anime here) as the top level entity in your schema i.e - create a new schema, unlike here, you would need to filter out the anime name from question->name->anime, also might have to worry about duplicates